# how do i make a JButton fill out two spaces in a gridlayout?

Tags: java, button, grid-layout

I have a JPanel set up with a GridLayout like this:

```
rightPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
```

In that gridlayout, I have a bunch of JButtons, how can I make one of those buttons take up two columns and one row, rather than just one row and one column?

Comment: share a snapshot of the desired output or provide a link of the image. Can you explain a bit more. How many buttons are there?

Answer (score 2):

You need [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) in this case instead of `GridLayout`.

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) where it is explained in details along with sample code of below snapshot.

Is this what you want?

[image]